# How to set kerberos authentication in fiddler

Tags: .net, web-services, web, fiddler

Is it possible to set kerberos authentication in fiddler - composer. Iam trying post a request to a service which is having kerberos authentication. Can any one please help me on how to do it... in Fiddler 2.

Rithesh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As explained in your private mail to me, Fiddler's Composer will automatically respond to authentication challenges (including the Negotiate protocol which wraps Kerberos) if you tick the Authentication box on the **Options** subtab.

If your system is performing Kerberos authentication using something *other* than Negotiate HTTP Authentication, you need to update your question with specific details of how authentication is being requested.